# Composition from multiple images using C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, png

I have a PictureBox on which images from files are painted, one on top of another (like a photoshop layering concept, if you're familiar). Being PNGs and with a opacity index, these images are perfect candidates for a image composition. But I can't figure out how to do that and save to a file.

In the following code sample, I've loaded two PNG images into bitmap objects and had them painted on the PictureBox.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle DesRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    Bitmap bmp;
    Rectangle SrcRec;

    bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\Res\\base.png");
    SrcRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, DesRec, SrcRec, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\Res\\layer1.png");
    SrcRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, DesRec, SrcRec, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

How do I save the composition to a file, preferably to another PNG file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start drawing to an intermediate in-memory bitmap, which I would then save (and eventually draw in your picture box, if really needed). Something like this:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    // ...
    graphics.DrawImage(...);
    // ...
}

bmp.Save("c:\\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Note that if you want to save the alpha channel (i.e. transparency) to the PNG file then you must create the bitmap with the appropriate pixel format: Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPargb)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks both of you. I've decided to do as Efran Cobisi suggested and changed the program so that it does the composing in memory first. Then I can use it where ever and however I want.

My new code to reflect the changes is as follows-

```
// Image objects to act as layers (which will hold the images to be composed)
Image Layer0 = new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + "\\Res\\base.png");
Image Layer1 = new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + "\\Res\\layer1.png");

//Creating the Canvas to draw on (I'll be saving/using this)
Image Canvas = new Bitmap(222, 225);

//Frame to define the dimentions
Rectangle Frame = new Rectangle(0, 0, 222, 225);

//To do drawing and stuffs
Graphics Artist = Graphics.FromImage(Canvas);

//Draw the layers on Canvas
Artist.DrawImage(Layer0, Frame, Frame, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
Artist.DrawImage(Layer1, Frame, Frame, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

//Free up resources when required
Artist.dispose();

//Show the Canvas in a PictureBox
pictureBox1.Image = Canvas;

//Save the Canvas image
Canvas.Save("MYIMG.PNG", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Apparently, the images (`Canvas`) are being saved with opacity index intact.